# Copy EFI partition to new disk in Windows Server 2008 RAID?

Tags: windows-server-2008, boot

I have the following RAID setup ( yes, disk 1 is failing :) ).

I need to copy the EFI partition from Disk 1 to the unallocated space in Disk 0, in order to make it bootable.

Does Windows provide a way to copy that partition? Or should I create one from scratch? If so, what is the correct way of doing it?

[image: RAID setup]